# Symfony2 - how can I set custom CORS Headers?

Tags: php, symfony, cors

I want to set following Headers for TWIG Template from within my DefaultController:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.mywebsite.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, *');
```

Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 36):

from [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20140306184401/http://blog.hio.fr/2013/04/30/symfony2-how-to-add-a-response-header-for-each-request.html) article:

**CorsListener.php**

```
<?php
namespace MyCorp\MyBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class CorsListener
{
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {   
        $responseHeaders = $event->getResponse()->headers;

        $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept');
        $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    }   
}
```

**services.yml**

```
app.cors_listener:
    class:      MyCorp\MyBundle\Listener\CorsListener
    tags:
       - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

Answer (score 30):

Using the response class:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
$response->send();
```

[Source/Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/http_fundamentals.html)

Comment: could this work?: $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: ', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');

Comment: I'm not at a computer where I can test it, but yes it should. I don't think you need the ":" after Access-Control-Allow-Methods though.

Comment: @zizoujab and @Edge and @allotherswithinterest: Yes, that works! I'm using tht for example to enforce the download of a CSV file: `$response->headers->set('Content-type', 'text/csv');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=file.csv');
$response->headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
$response->headers->set('Expires', '0');`

Answer (score 3):

If its inside controller then use this:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        ...    
        $response = new Response($xmlContent);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'xml');
        $response->headers->set('Another-Header', 'header-value');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Just replace Content-Type with your header key and xml with value ... etc

Comment: Should we replace `xml` with `application/xml`?

Comment: Also if you're using $this->render() from the controller, what's the equivalent when rendering templates via the response object?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `render()` method of the controller, then you can add the necessary headers like below because `render()` method returns a Response object:

```php
$response = $this->render('AppBundle:Post:index.html.twig', array('someArgs' => $someArgs));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
return $response;
```