# Symfony2 : allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin with google charts

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy

In my Symfony application, I am using google charts.

I get an error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/dca88b1ff7033fac80178eb526cb263e/ui+en.css. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://foodmeup.dev' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've tried to get around this by setting a listener which adds headers to the response (see the cors listener here : [Symfony2 - how can I set custom Headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472333/symfony2-how-can-i-set-custom-headers)) and it's not working, I get the same error.

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class CorsListener
{
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $responseHeaders = $response->headers;

    $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept');
    $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');

    $event->setResponse($response);
}
}
```

In my view I use a simple google chart :

```
<div class="piechart margin-auto" style="height: 220px;" data-completeness="{{ completeness }}"></div>

<script>var googleCharts = [];</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function drawProfilePieCharts()
        {
            var completeness = $(this).data('completeness');

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Nom',    'Valeur'],
                ["Profil rempli à ", completeness],
                ['Manque', 100 - completeness]
            ]);

            var options = {
                backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent'},
                pieSliceBorderColor : 'transparent',
                pieHole: 0.8,
                legend: {position: 'top'},
                width: 220,
                height: 220,
                tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
                pieStartAngle: -90,
                pieSliceTextStyle :{fontsize : 16, color: 'transparent'},
                slices: {
                    0: { color: '#09b4ff'},
                    1: { color: '#444'}
                },
                chartArea : {width: '90%', height: '90%'}
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(this);
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

        googleCharts.push("$('.piechart').each(drawProfilePieCharts)");

    $(window).resize(function(){
        drawAllCharts();
    });


    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart', 'bar', 'line']});
    var drawAllCharts = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < googleCharts.length; i++) {
            eval(googleCharts[i]);
        }
    };

    google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){drawAllCharts()});

    </script>
```

Comment: Can you show your backend code?

Comment: If you mean the code to add headers to the response, I've copied the cors listener from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472333/symfony2-how-can-i-set-custom-headers

Comment: You are not setting headers to the $response. You're setting them to $responseHeaders

Answer (score 8):

Tried to just set the header on the response, and it worked:

```
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://foodmeup.dev');
```

Take into account that the URL MUST BE exactly the one that's expected, with HTTP or HTTPS and no / at the end.

It's possible to set more than one of these headers, in my case i used 4, HTTP and HTTPS, dev and prod servers. All worked fine.

Comment: You can use '*' to allow all URLs.

Answer (score 4):

A good thing here is to use kernel events subscriber, such as:

```
class Toto implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => 'onKernelResponse'
        );
    }

    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $httpRequestOrigin = $event->getRequest()->headers->get('origin');

        $event->getResponse()->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $httpRequestOrigin);
        $event->getResponse()->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me a lot)

Answer (score 3):

Try this::

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$xmlContent = 'Your XML content';

$response = new Response();

$response->setContent($xmlContent);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://foodmeup.dev');

// prints the headers followed by the content
$response->send();
```

*Not tested*

**Edit:**

You may have to set the event response:

```
$response = $event->getResponse();

$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept');
    ...

$event->setResponse($response);
```

Comment: well, I need to keep it iin my listener cause I won't change every response or I need a more general solution. setting the url you indicated does not work. setting the content-type as text/xml is contrary to the meta tags I have apparently.

Comment: I've seen your edited question. Check my new answer.

Comment: thanks for trying. i've updated the response event, it's not working either. Can I actually do something ? Is that not the headers of the response from google that is missing this allow-access parameter?

Comment: Mmh, probably. I have no idea about Google Chart.